# How do I write logs and display them real-time in a Java Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, logging

I have created a GUI program that uses a class to perform some tasks.

I would like to add logging in both the `JFrame` and the class. Logs should be kept in a file and displayed in a `JTextArea` concurrently.

What is a convient solution for this?

Comment: with regard to logging, try [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/)

Comment: What have you done so far? It sounds like you need to pick your favorite Logging framework (either java.util.logging or log4j) and wrap it with some class/instance that simply writes to your `JTextArea`.

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/a/33657637/808901

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a wrapper that

1. updates your JTextArea
2. logs via [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/), [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) or [Apache Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/) or another logging framework

> ```
> public void log(String msg) {
>       appendToJTextArea(msg);
>       LOG.info(msg);
>  }
> ```

Comment: And why not simply "write to a file using a printstream"?

Comment: Because a logging framework is doing nothing else. PLUS you can customize it, turn it on/off easily, create customer appenders/loggers, have different loglevels, ... So why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using a simple `System.out.println()` call and then running your application like this:

```
java -cp path/to/my/class/or/jar/MyClass.class MyClass -debug > myLog.log
```

Which will create a text pane for you (`-debug` parameter), as well as put them in a log file for you.

Comment: Come on, this is ridiculous! Logging frameworks are easy to use and if you one don't know about them it's investment for the future to learn this. `System.out.println()` is ok for a HelloWorld or debugging problems with you logging framework, but not for real applications. Please look at timbooo's answer describing a wrapper class.

Comment: @Thor: Indeed, real applications should not work this way. But I gave a +1 because of a simple alternative, using something that already exists. I didn't know this option. And yes, I gave timbooo also a +1.

Comment: @Thor, I fully understand logging, I have made my own framework for that in objective-c. However, I meant this to be a simple way that the OP can log data, without any extra writing of code.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can log to a file easily is to use a FileWriter:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

Additionally, as you log data you can always update the text of a JTextArea with JTextArea.append():
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html

If you're logging to a file, might I suggest logging to multiple timestamped files? This ensures that you're saving the data and that you won't lose too much in the event of a program crash.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Those links are to an old version of Java.