# Listening for Log Messages in slf4j/logback

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

I have a Swing-based application without a console that logs all messages to text files through slf4j with logback underneath.

Whenever a message is logged, I'd also like to add it to a `JTextArea` for the end user to see on the screen.

These messages should be formatted the sameway as the log files for consistency.

Does slf4j/logback have API that lets you add a listener for log messages so that I can copy them to `JTextArea`?

Comment: Check my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33657637/808901

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Logback [Appenders](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) are listeners for log messages. Just implement a custom appender that will log 
in a `JTextArea`.

You can then create, configure and add appenders to loggers programmatically, or using an external config file (`logback.xml`)

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way.  I've done the same thing.  I created an appender that formats the messages and stores them in a circular buffer.  The the UI can get the circula buffer, via a singleton, and display the log lines.  But why format to a text line, better to display as a grid.