# Logging in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, logging, user-interface, jtextarea

I am developing a GUI with a `JTextArea` to show certain messages. Two kind of messages might appear here: those written on purpose and intended for the user (*"Task completed"*, *"No file found"*, *"Please wait"*...) and those for the developer (information about exceptions, warnings, help messages...).

- So far, I am considering two options to show information on the `JTextArea`: use the `setText()` method, or use `System.out.print()` and redirect the output stream to the `JTextArea`.

Which option is better? Why?

- How can I implement a system to allow the user to select which kind
  of messages are to be showed on the `JTextArea`? Something like a `JComboBox` with different options, so the User can select if he/she wants to get just Application Messages, or messages related to the workflow (warnings, exceptions, etc.)

Comment: Have you considered using a logging library? A library like log4j or logback would allow you to write a custom appender to log to a JTextArea. Control over the logging level is also a base feature of the logging libraries.

Comment: Since its related to logging, consider `append()`over `setText()`, `setText()` will simply `replace/override` the previous value of the component concern, whereas the former will add `more` to the previous value. You can try this behaviour, simply by changing `append()` with `setText()` in the working code mentioned in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17763395/1057230)

Comment: Check my logback solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33657637/808901

Answer (score 4):

1. I would just use `setText()`. Using `System.out.println()` and redirecting to the `JTextArea` would make things needlessly more complex.
2. If you have a component that collects messages (which are then displayed by the `JTextArea`), you could change it so you do not only supply a message but also something like a `Category`. Depending on the content of the `JComboBox`, only messages of a certain `Category` would be displayed inside the `JTextArea`.

If I may suggest a somewhat different approach: maybe you're using something like Log4J or Logback inside your application to log messages. It might well be able to register a custom appender for your logging framework that redirects to the `JTextArea`. This approach might be a bit more work to get it running, but it could allow for greater flexibility - and not re-inventing a wheel that already exists.

My two cents on how to do this would be to have something like a `FeedbackManager` (I just made up the name, so feel free to make up a better name). This `FeedbackManager` would be a singleton, all classes that use it would refer to the same instance. Whenever you need to present a message to the user, post it to the `FeedbackManager`, including the `Category` (see above). When the `FeedbackManager` receives a `Message`, it should inform all its listeners that a new message was posted.

When instantiating the `JTextArea`, register an anonymous listener to the `FeedbackManager`; when the listener is called, it can check whether the message must be displayed based on the selection of the `JComboBox`, and if so, append it to the `JTextArea`.

Comment: I am not using any framework to log messages. Could you post some example for beginners  of what you propose? I have no experience and that would be awesome ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want use to an extra logging library (if the program is small, or if you have to save space (for example in an applet)...), you can always use the logging in JSE: java.util.logging.
If so, you can use a Handler to write to the text component:

```
final class TextComponentHandler extends Handler {
  @Nonnull private final JTextArea text;
    TextComponentHandler(@Nonnull JTextArea text) {
      this.text = text;
    }
  @Override
  public void publish(LogRecord record) {
    if (isLoggable(record))
      synchronized(text) {
        text.append(getFormatter().format(record));
      }
  }
  @Override
  public void flush() {/**/}
  @Override
  public void close() throws SecurityException {/**/}
}
```

and add it with:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea() {
  @Override
  public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();
    for(Handler hh : logger.getHandlers())
      if (hh == h)
        return;
    logger.addHandler(h);
  }
  @Override
  public void removeNotify() {
    super.removeNotify();
    logger.removeHandler(h);
  }
};
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("my.logger");
Handler h = new TextComponentHandler(textArea);
logger.addHandler(h);
```

Comment: I liked the approach or the intent, but How good this approach is, I can not comment on that, +1 I hope `addNotify()` can be used in this way

Comment: At least it is code that actually works, I use it in production